# Скачать файлы с сайта, которые появляются на сайте после ввода названия самого файла

Tags: python

Нужно скачать файлы с сайта.

На сайте эти файлы появляются после того, как в поиске (на самом сайте в строке) вводишь название файла. И поместить все эти файлы в какую-либо папку.

Заранее спасибо))

Answer (score 0):

Ну как минимум чтоб написать полностью код нужен сайт

Плюс ко всему писать код полностью за вас тут никто не будет

Вот код, который вы можете адаптировать под себя для этого вопроса и в след раз скидывай ваш вариант кода для вопроса

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import os

# название файла для поиска
file_name = "example.txt"

# URL сайта для поиска файлов
url = "https://example.com/search?q=" + file_name

# путь к папке для сохранения файлов
download_path = "path/to/download/folder"

# создаем папку, если ее еще нет
if not os.path.exists(download_path):
    os.makedirs(download_path)

# загружаем страницу с результатами поиска
response = requests.get(url)

# создаем объект soup для парсинга HTML-кода страницы
soup = BeautifulSoup(response.content, "html.parser")

# находим все ссылки на странице
links = soup.find_all("a")

# проходимся по каждой ссылке и скачиваем файлы
for link in links:
    # проверяем, является ли ссылка ссылкой на файл
    if link.get("href").endswith(".txt") or link.get("href").endswith(".pdf"):
        # формируем URL для скачивания файла
        file_url = link.get("href")
        
        # скачиваем файл
        file_response = requests.get(file_url)
        
        # сохраняем файл в указанную папку
        file_path = os.path.join(download_path, os.path.basename(file_url))
        with open(file_path, "wb") as f:
            f.write(file_response.content)
            
        print("Файл {} загружен".format(file_url))
```